# Set the color for QFont

Tags: c++, qt, qfont

I have a 'QGraphicsScene' scene and am trying to use

```
addText(const QString &text, const QFont &font = QFont())
```

to add some texts to the scene. It worked. But, I tried to change the text color but could NOT find a way to set the color for 'QFont'. I did not find 'font.setColor' type method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks. It does work. However, if possible, I still would like to know: Do we have a way to set the color for a QFont type class?

Answer (score 0):

In Qt the color is not part of QFont. Did you try addText()->setDefaultTextColor()?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried and worked. However, if possible, I still would like to know: Do we have a way to set the color for a QFont type class?

Comment: As far as I know, thats not possible. Qt library is structured in a way, where the color is not part of the Font.